# MySQL query in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have two tables: *restaurants* and *restaurant_order*.

```
restaurants: 

    +----+-----------------+-------+
    | id |      item       | price |
    +----+-----------------+-------+
    | 1  | Hot & Sour Soup | 2.5   |
    | 2  | Manchurian Soup | 2.5   |
    | 3  | Hummus          | 1.8   |
    | 4  | Tabouleh        | 1.5   |
    | .  | .               | .     |
    | .  | .               | .     |
    | .  | .               | .     |
    | 8  | Cake (slice)    | 2     |
    +----+-----------------+-------+

restaurant_orders: 

    +----+------------+---------------+----------+
    | id | booking_id | restaurant_id | quantity |
    +----+------------+---------------+----------+
    |  1 |         13 |             3 |        2 |
    |  2 |         15 |             9 |        1 |
    |  3 |         15 |             1 |        1 |
    |  4 |         13 |             8 |        2 |
    |  5 |         15 |             8 |        3 |
    |  6 |         15 |            11 |        1 |
    |  7 |         13 |            10 |        2 |
    +----+------------+---------------+----------+
```

The table restaurant_orders stores the data of booking and item ordered.
I am trying to display (in graph) the number of times specific items have been ordered.So multiplying with quantity.

**Controller**

```
public function restaurant(){
    $data = DB::table('restaurant_orders')
    ->join('restaurants', 'restaurant_id', '=', 'restaurants.id')
    ->select(
        DB::raw('item as item'),
        DB::raw('count(*) * quantity as total'))
    ->groupBy('item','quantity')
    ->get();

    $array[]=['Item', 'Total'];

    foreach($data as $key=>$value)
    {
     $array[++$key] = [$value->item, $value->total];
    }

    return view('executive.restaurant')->with('item',json_encode($array));
}
```

The output I am getting:

```
+-------------------+-------+
|       Item        | Total |
+-------------------+-------+
| Cake (slice)      |     2 |
| Cake (slice)      |     3 |
| Fried Rice        |     1 |
| Hot & Sour Soup   |     1 |
| Hummus            |     2 |
| Soft Drinks       |     2 |
| Vanilla milkshake |     1 |
+-------------------+-------+
```

I don't want the same item to be repeated as seen above for 'cake (slice)'. I want it to be like:

```
+-------------------+-------+
|       Item        | Total |
+-------------------+-------+
| Cake (slice)      |     5 |
| Fried Rice        |     1 |
| Hot & Sour Soup   |     1 |
| Hummus            |     2 |
| Soft Drinks       |     2 |
| Vanilla milkshake |     1 |
+-------------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

```
public function restaurant() {
    $data = DB::table('restaurant_orders')
    ->join('restaurants', 'restaurant_id', '=', 'restaurants.id')
    ->select(
        DB::raw('item as item'),
        DB::raw('sum(1 * quantity) as total')) 
    ->groupBy('item')
    ->get();

    $array[]=['Item', 'Total'];

    foreach($data as $key=>$value) {
        $array[++$key] = [$value->item, (int) $value->total];
    }

    return view('executive.restaurant')->with('item', json_encode($array));
}
```

Changing the query to `sum(1 * quantity) as total` and `(int) $value->total` solved the issue. This was arising due to Google Charts.

Comment: It is giving an error. 
**SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '*) as total from `restaurant_orders` inner join `restaurants` on `restaurant_id`' at line 1 (SQL: select item as item, sum(*) as total from `restaurant_orders` inner join `restaurants` on `restaurant_id` = `restaurants`.`id` group by `item`)** after I used your query.

Comment: so for some odd reason it's not including the `*` try changing `sum(*)` to `sum(1)` see if that helps... if not I suggest looking into some tutorials on how to do sum selects in the ORM Laravel is using...

Comment: I tried using your logic to solve the issue, which I have already tried before as well. I don't want it to be `sum()` for items, I want that every item shows how many times they were ordered. Your query is giving me how many times they were ordered without including the 'quantity' column to be multiplied. Still thank you for trying to help me, I appreciate it.

Comment: so why not just multiply the sum here with the sum of quantity?

Comment: If you mean by using the sum of items and then multiplying with the sum of quantity then it isn't working. Maybe you can send me a query of what you are trying to explain to me so I understand it better?

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: It isn't working still, it's multiplying the entire sum of quantities for the cake(slice) only. Also the graph is not being displayed because of it.

Comment: can you please add the result for my query? before it goes to the graph... I don't know which graph you are using... Also, is there a way for you to generate the SQL query that this code does? I need more information here to try and figure out what else is needed :)

Comment: I solved it, thank you for your help! I did use your logic but I did a silly mistake which was the reason it failed to get the output. thank you!